# Reducing Multiple Actions/Filter optimization with Transformations in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a master dataset (df) out of which I am trying to create averages based on certain filters.
[image]

```
F1 = df.filter((df.Identifier1>0)).groupBy().avg('Amount')
F2 = df.filter((df.Identifier1>2)).groupBy().avg('Amount')

F3 = df.filter((df.Identifier2<2)).groupBy().avg('Amount')
F4 = df.filter((df.Identifier2<4)).groupBy().avg('Amount')

#Alternatively also tried another way for avg calculation,
F1 = df.filter((df.Identifier1>0)).agg(avg(col('Amount')))
..
```

Post Calculating these averages, I am trying to assign them to the records in the master df into two columns A1 and A2 ***using the same filters used in average calculation***.

```
df = df.withColumn("A1", when((col("Identifier1") > 0)), (F1.collect()[0][0]))
       ….
       ….
       .otherwise(avg(col('Amount')))

df = df.withColumn("A2", when((col("Identifier2") <2 )), (F3.collect()[0][0]))
       ….
       ….
       .otherwise(avg(col('Amount')))
```

I am facing two issues:

1. When one of the averages is Null then I get an error while calling `collect() or first()`

   Error:
   `Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [null]`
2. As there are multiple actions involved the process takes over 2hrs.

Any help on the above is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a column for your filter conditions, e.g.

```
+---+--------+-----------+-----------+------+
| ID|Category|Identifier1|Identifier2|Amount|
+---+--------+-----------+-----------+------+
| 12|       A|          2|          1|   100|
| 23|       B|          7|          8|   500|
| 34|       C|          1|          4|   300|
+---+--------+-----------+-----------+------+

df.withColumn('group', when(df.Identifier1 > 0, array(lit(1))).otherwise(array(lit(None)))) \
  .withColumn('group', when(df.Identifier1 > 2, array_union(col('group'), array(lit(2)))).otherwise(col('group'))) \
  .withColumn('group', when(df.Identifier2 < 2, array_union(col('group'), array(lit(3)))).otherwise(col('group'))) \
  .withColumn('group', when(df.Identifier2 < 4, array_union(col('group'), array(lit(4)))).otherwise(col('group'))) \
  .withColumn('group', explode('group')) \
  .groupBy('group').agg(sum('Amount').alias('sum'), avg('Amount').alias('avg')).show()

+-----+---+-----+
|group|sum|  avg|
+-----+---+-----+
|    1|900|300.0|
|    3|100|100.0|
|    4|100|100.0|
|    2|500|500.0|
+-----+---+-----+
```

and then group by to the group.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the “when” part and how to group by group further? Thanks

Comment: Getting the average as desired. Only issue is that when I collect attached it to a grouping rule which is empty, error is : ```grouping expressions sequence is empty``` Any suggestions?